# Properties and Allocating Memory

Tags: swift, memory-management

I am hacking my way through Swift.  I love it but I find myself thinking a few things may be too simple and I question if it's correct.

I am converting a project from Objective-C.  In the project I have a string property that is use in a method.  In Objective-C I did the following to initialize and allocate the object.  Once it's initialized and allocated I set it to an empty string.

```
NSMutableString *tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
self.currentParsedCharacterData = tempString;
[currentParsedCharacterData setString: @""];
```

In Swift I typed the following.  Is it really this easy or am I missing something?

```
self.currentParsedCharacterData = ""
```

I find myself wanting to do the following but I'm not sure it's necessary.

```
var tempString : String = ""
self.currentParsedCharacterData = tempString
```

Take care,

Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, its this easy. In Objective-C, you could have typed `self.currentParsedCharacterData = @"".mutableCopy` and achieved the same effect.

`@""` in Objective-C and `""` in Swift are object literals that allocate memory and initialise for you. Equally for arrays, you can do `@[]` for an empty `NSArray` or `[]` for an empty `Array` (in Swift) to allocate and initialise an empty array.